# No data to display GridView Asp Net DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

i try to make gridview in devexpress and its work but if i click next page, page get message No data to display.
i try to make from asp net, but same problem no data display.
How to fix that ? sorry im newbie for this.

This is my code for aspx :

```
<dx:BootstrapGridView runat="server" ID="GVcity" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <SettingsEditing Mode="Inline"></SettingsEditing>
                <SettingsDataSecurity AllowEdit="true" AllowDelete="true" AllowInsert="true"  />
                <SettingsBehavior AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="true" AllowSelectByRowClick="true" /> 
                <Columns>
                    <dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn FieldName="localRegionName" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Regional"></dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn>
                    <dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn FieldName="localRegionCode" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Code"></dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn>
                    <dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn FieldName="CityName" VisibleIndex="2" Caption="City"></dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn>
                </Columns>
                    <Settings ShowFilterRow="true" ShowFilterRowMenu="true"  />

               
            </dx:BootstrapGridView>
```

and this is my code for cs :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        
            this.BindGrid();
        
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tblcity.localRegionCode, tblcity.CityName, tbllocalregion.localRegionName FROM tblcity, tbllocalregion where tblcity.localRegionCode = tbllocalregion.localRegionCode"))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GVcity.DataSource = dt;
                        GVcity.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GVcity.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

i try to show data from mysql, and i dont know what i miss ???

Comment: Why are you using old-fashined [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) (via `where` statement) instead of correct one?

Comment: its show for first page, but to next page no data showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<dx:BootstrapGridView runat="server" ID="GVcity" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" OnPageIndexChanged="GVcity_PageIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn FieldName="localRegionName" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Regional"></dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn>
                     
                    <dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn FieldName="localRegionCode" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Code"></dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn>
                    <dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn FieldName="CityName" VisibleIndex="2" Caption="City"></dx:BootstrapGridViewTextColumn>
                    <dx:BootstrapGridViewCommandColumn ShowClearFilterButton="true" ShowApplyFilterButton="true" VisibleIndex="3" />
                </Columns>
                    
            </dx:BootstrapGridView>
```